# DAG Level Access Control (Airflow 1.10.4)

Tags: airflow

I use Airflow 1.10.4, created a role `test_role` and a user `test_user` with that role.  I also created a DAG with `access_control`

```
with DAG(DAG_NAME,
     schedule_interval='@daily',
     default_args=default_args,
     access_control={
         'test_role': {'can_dag_read'},
     },
     ) as dag:
DummyOperator(task_id='run_this_1') >> DummyOperator(
    task_id='run_this_2') >> DummyOperator(task_id='run_this_3')
```

but when I login using that user, I didn’t see this DAG. anything wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess access control parm is not released yet. Kindly refer [airflow jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-5024) and [change log](https://airflow.apache.org/changelog.html).

As a workaround, we can go with webUI access control options.

If you find any promising solution please let me know as well. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to execute "airflow sync_perm" on your Airflow WebServer.